# Getting Error 404 Not Found when deployed asp.net core web api to aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

So i built a asp.net core web api app on .NET 5.0 , it works completely fine on my machine . Today i deployed it on elastic beanstalk AWS using the aws tools .
It doesn't show any error while deploying and stuff. it just returns me code 404 not found.
Here is my code.

```
using Startup.cs
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using ShopApiNet5.Authentication;
using ShopApiNet5.Models;


namespace ShopApiNet5
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("ModelDB"));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ModelContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })

            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
                };
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "ShopApi", Version = "V1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "Bearer"
                                }
                            },
                            new string[] {}

                    }
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TodoApi v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my launchsettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "launchUrl": "swagger",
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://shopapinetsm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/",
      "sslPort": 44352
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ShopApiNet5": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      //"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "applicationUrl": "http://shopapinetsm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the link to view the latest log

https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-676277819872.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-afp9eu4yxa/i-00e8df513fd738529/TailLogs-1636655753712.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211111T183555Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86399&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIOUOORMVUTXOJUHQ%2F20211111%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=af742a78702d5d2e8131fe07d96e15b83449ffcbdacb0912a15acec32f371e3e

Please help me

Comment: I'm now trying to remake this project using standard asp.net core web application template, not a web api one. hope this helps me

Comment: Didn't help, having the same problem...
http://shopapismnet5webapp-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ the link to my remade app , on a simple web app template

Comment: I tried to deploy a default template web api app , without https enabled. it deployed but environment is not responsive, im so sad

Comment: I clicked on your log, and the error message Request has expired appeared. I checked the information. To solve this problem, the owner of the object must generate a new pre-signed URL with a new expiration date. If you are the owner of the object, please refer to pre-signing or sharing the object with others for instructions.

Comment: Thank you @Chaodeng , i actually. fixed this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just made a new app without https enabling, and it just worked as i remember.